# Cannot read property 'value' of null while accessing js variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

what i  Need

- i need to pass url variable from html to javascript file.

html code

```
    <script>
     var p = "{{ page_param.asy_request | replace('&','&')}}";
     p = p.replace(/\&/g, "&");
     p = "{{ DomainDetect() }}/ajax?for=event_listing&ajax=1" + p;

   </script>

 <input type="hidden" name="mobilepage" id="mobilepage" value="'+p+'"/>
```

Accesing p variable in javascript code

```
   var mobile=document.getElementById("mobilepage").value;
   console.log(mobile);
```

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

- i need url should be passed from html file to js file.
- i have used hidden element for that.
- any suggestion are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your html element hasn't id. Hence you can't select using the `document.getElementById`. If you want to fix this, you have to add this `id`, like below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mobilepage" id="mobilepage" value=""/>
```

If you don't want to add an `id` and you want to leave this element as is, the you should use another method for selecting your element, `document.getElementByName`.

Below I have added a code snippet to see that it works.

```js
alert(document.getElementById("mobilepage").value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="mobilepage" id="mobilepage" value="3"/>
```

Comment: @user3785613 have you added the `id` and it didn't?

Comment: updated <script>
var p = "{{ page_param.asy_request | replace('&','&')}}";
p = p.replace(/\&/g, "&");
p = "{{ DomainDetect() }}/ajax?for=event_listing&ajax=1" + p;
console.log(p);
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="mobilepage" id="mobilepage" value='"+p+"'/>

Comment: js file var mobile=document.getElementById("mobilepage").value;
console.log(mobile);

Comment: @user3785613 I think that your problem relies on the way you have defined the `value`.

Comment: alert(document.getElementById("mobilepage") return null

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get an element by ID, when you should be getting that element by name.
Do:

```
 var mobile=document.getElementByName("mobilepage").value;
```

Either that, or change the name to be an ID on the HTML element:

```
<input type="hidden" id="mobilepage" value=""/>
```

Comment: still the same problem  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: updated <input type="hidden" name="mobilepage" id="mobilepage" value="'+p+'"/>

Comment: @user3785613 If it doesn't work then you have a mismatch between your scripts and the DOM elements, because the element is clearly not available, thus returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Add id attribute to your input.